# Clonezilla automatic restore

Tags: clonezilla

I'm using an automatic disk restoring system with Clonezilla via USB key.
My USB key is partitioned in two different device: the first partition with the ISO of the disk I want to restore (labeled as ISO) and the second one with the Clonezilla (labeled as CLONEZILLA).
I wrote an entry to automate the restore using all the parameters that I need.
Below you can read the problematic piece of the entry.

```
ocs_prerun="mount /dev/sda1 /home/partimag"
```

The problem is, sometimes the ISO device is detected as sda1 and sometimes as sdb1. Is there a way to specify the label of the device to mount? Something like /media/user/ISO used in Linux.
I can't find the answer to this question anywhere.

Comment: When this `mount` runs, are `/dev/disk/by-uuid/` and other `/dev/disk/by-*/` (or similar) directories available and populated? If so, use a proper file (symlink) from therein instead of `/dev/sda1`. Or does this `mount` support `-U`? See the answers to [*how to mount by UUID without using `/etc/fstab`*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/349118/108618). Or maybe you can modify `fstab` in the first place (I totally don't know).